# Make Opencart 1.5.6 multi-store share same cart over multiple Top-level Domain

Tags: php, session, e-commerce, opencart, session-cookies

I wanna ask if there's a way that I can make my opencart multi-store in just one session. For example, if I login to store1, then I went to store 2, I don't need to login anymore. Also, if I didn't login but I added a product from store1, when I go to store2, the product that I added in store1 is still on the cart (adding product first before login).

I've tried all the solutions of the links below but none of them worked:

[how to make opencart multi-store share same cart over multiple TLDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252844/how-to-make-opencart-multi-store-share-same-cart-over-multiple-tlds)

[Opencart cart across multiple stores with different subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066759/opencart-cart-across-multiple-stores-with-different-subdomains)

[Opencart Multi-store 1.5.6 shared session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744252/opencart-multi-store-1-5-6-shared-session)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what attempts you have made to do this?

Comment: @RegisteredUser Done adding. Please see the post again.

Comment: I'm not experienced with this stuff, sorry. I'll give you some general advice. Can you post any error messages or whatever shows up?

Comment: No errors. It's when I login to store1 then I added an item in the cart, then I go to store2, I need to login again to see the items in the cart. I want to make it that if I login to store1, when I go to store2, I'm already logged in. @RegisteredUser

Comment: @RegisteredUser idk about this stuff but this might have to do with cookies... i might be wrong. Make some edits on your answer to bump it up to the top of the front page so that other people can see it.